# What is the host url of Oracle cloud Application Express?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I have signed up for the trial version of oracle cloud data base.

Where can I find the host URL that I need to use in my Java dynamic web project of eclipse?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Basic knowledge about the trial request and details needed :** 
After you request a trial service from Oracle Cloud, you'll be provided with a few details: Identity Domain, Temporary password, and your username.

By using them you'll login to your trial cloud account from here:
[https://cloud.oracle.com/sign_in][1]

**Accessing the service from Eclipse**

When it comes to access your Database Cloud Service from Eclipse:

1. You need to add the Oracle Cloud plugin from the Eclipse Market (Help Menu->Eclipse Marketplace)
2. You'll add the Oracle Cloud connection window to the interface (Window Menu->Show View->Other)
3. Create a new connection where you follow the steps with the proper details you have about your account.